# Is std::string terminated with '/0'?

Tags: c++

```
char *pt = "hello";
std::string str = "hello";
```

Does `str` also end with `'/0'` (is null terminated)?

Comment: maybe? `str.data()` will give you null terminated c string, aside from that you don't really care.

Comment: This question doesn't quite make sense as-is. `std::string` is neither an array nor a pointer, it's a class. How would you define what it "ends with"?

Comment: @yngum Also `&str[0]` and `str.c_str()`.

Comment: The accepted answer of that question doesn't state that it must be null terminated (or even contiguous?!), but neither here or there do we see quotes from the C++ spec.

Answer (score 3):

It is implementation defined whether or not `std::string` is null-terminated.

The actual contents of `str` after its definition:

```
std::string str = "hello";
```

are characters `'h'`, `'e'`, `'l'`, `'l'`, `'o'` and its `size` is equal only to 5 characters.

Comment: While this is true, the standard also requires that the underlying controlled sequence be zero terminated when you access it via either `c_str`, `data` or `operator[]` member functions.

Comment: do you make sure that str isn't end with '\o'

Answer (score 2):

The buffer manged by `str` MAY be null terminated, but not necessarily.

Comment: Actually, as I reckon, C++(11?) requires `&str[0]` to point to `str.c_str()`.

Comment: @H2CO3 That is indeed the case with C++11. Not so much with previous versions, however.

Answer (score 0):

`str.c_str()` will provide you a `const char*`, which pointed to a null-terminated, contiguous buffer (like your `"hello"` string literal was).

But be aware of using `&str[0]` because it's not guaranteed that this points to a contiguous buffer, neither that this buffer is null-terminated.